# Does picking up an adult cat by neck cause them to be paralyzed like kittens?

Tags: cats, behavior, biology, animal-handling

When kittens are picked up by the neck by their mothers the kittens become temporarily paralyzed.

Is this also true for adult cats if a human was to pick them up the same way?

Comment: never ever pick up an adult cat by the neck.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE picking up an adult cat by the neck will cause pain and injuries, because of the much bigger weight of adult cats, compared to kittens

Comment: Male cats use this reaction to subdue a female during sex

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Cats can be temporarily paralyzed by pinching the skin on the back of their neck. This is called "pinch-induced behavioral inhibition" (PIBI) or "scruffing" or "clipnosis" (a composition of clip and hypnosis, because clips are often used in veterinary or scientific settings to keep cats immobile). It is a reflex in cats and other animals like rodents, rabbits, guinea pigs and dogs. **This reflex stays active as the animal ages.** You can read more about it in [What research is there on the long term effects of pinch-induced behavioral inhibition conditioning on cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1522/12501).

**However**, the skin of the neck can only support a limited amount of weight and is **not suited to support the body weight of an adult cat.** You will certainly cause your cat pain and potentially injure it by literally picking it up by the scruff of the neck. Please read more about it in [Is it ok to pick my adult cat up by the scruff of the neck?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1003/12501)

Comment: Just to point out that not all cats respond to this - one of our pair responds exactly as expected, the other pretty much ignores it completely and just acts confused